# ¿Como obtener el archivo anterior y siguiente con botones de pyqt5?

Tags: python, bucles, pyqt5

Estoy usando python y la librería pyqt5. Mi código obtiene el nombre de un archivo dentro de una carpeta, se compara para saber cuales son los archivos con extensión .gif y finalmente se le asigna a la variable MyGif. Pero en el ciclo que tengo únicamente se obtiene el ultimo archivo.

¿Como puedo obtener el nombre de cualquiera de los archivos que existen en la carpeta uno por uno según lo requiera el usuario y no solamente el ultimo?

```
dir=os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    root, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if extension == ".gif":
       MyGif=filename
```

En este caso, como puedo obtener el nombre de cada archivo para que el usuario los pueda visualizar uno por uno con botones de siguiente y anterior. Como si fuera un reproductor de música.

Comment: `os.listdir()` nunca devuelve un solo elemento, si solo obtienes 1entonces algo haces mal

Comment: Eso lo se, la pregunta es mas bien como acceder a los elementos uno por uno. Creo que la pregunta no se entendía pero ya la modifique.

Comment: almacena los resultados en una lista `MyGifs = [ os.path.splitext(filename)[1] for filename in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".gif"  ]`